# Removing duplicates rooms from Outlook?

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013, calendar

I know that this is by design, is there away to remove the duplicates from the room lists permanently?

Some dated recommendations but nothing to recent.

Followed the KB https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/75e2ac80-577e-46c7-90b9-7b6ae4b84051/duplicate-room-lists-appearing-under-room-finder?forum=outlook

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences

It does clear the list after the restart, however when booking new rooms it repopulates the data in Outlook as well as the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research and test, there seems to no way to change the default behavior :(